# how to compare a label in a Custom UITableViewCel if its empty or not?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

i have a custom TableViewCell with 2 dateLabels, when nothing is saved with coreData, my dateLabel should select a sample date. But when a date is set i want to show it in my Label. 
i tried it with the following code but i doesn't work properly.

can you help me please?

here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"produktCell";


    ProduktTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ProduktTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    }
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    cell.produktnameLabel.text = [managedObject valueForKey:@"produktname"]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",cell.vonDatumLabel.text);

    if ([cell.vonDatumLabel.text length] > 1){
        cell.vonDatumLabel.text = [managedObject valueForKey:@"vondatum"];
        cell.bisDatumLabel.text = [managedObject valueForKey:@"bisdatum"]; 

    }else {
        cell.vonDatumLabel.text = dateString;
        cell.bisDatumLabel.text = dateString1;
    }



        cell.datumButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.warenkorbButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.menge.tag = indexPath.row + 437812;
    cell.mengeLabel.text = [managedObject valueForKey:@"mengelabel"];




    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *german = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de_DE"];
    [formatter setLocale:german];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];


    NSNumber *firstNumber = [managedObject valueForKey:@"preis"];

    cell.preisLabel.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:firstNumber];



    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Quick question: Are you successfully retrieving data from Core Data?

Comment: Try with isEqualtoString property of label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Make if condition like this 

if ([[managedObject valueForKey:@"produktname"] length] > 1){
        cell.vonDatumLabel.text = [managedObject valueForKey:@"vondatum"];
        cell.bisDatumLabel.text = [managedObject valueForKey:@"bisdatum"]; 

    }else {
        cell.vonDatumLabel.text = dateString;
        cell.bisDatumLabel.text = dateString1;
    }

Surely this will help ful
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this I think this will work for you.

```
   [cell.vonDatumLabel.text isEqualToString: dateString];
   [cell.bisDatumLabel.text isEqualToString: dateString1];
```